# BASH extract link href from a string

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a bash variable that contains something like this:

```
<a onclick="return:false;" href="https://example.com/file-X.Y.Z.zip"><div class="btn">Linux</div></a>
```

What I'd like to do is to extract the href part. I need to obtain the filename, indeed.

How can I do that? I've already tried with `sed` and `awk`, with no much luck... I'm completely newbie with those tools though, so it's certainly my fault.

Comment: Your best bet is to not use bash to parse HTML.

Comment: I know, I could do that in PHP quite fast, but I need to use BASH this time...

Comment: You can call a snippet of other code from bash. That's what calling sed or awk does, after all.

Comment: PHP, Node, Python, Ruby, even Perl would be 100x better than bash. Bash is simply incapable of doing this in a general purpose sense. This is like opening a can with a screwdriver: It's possible but fundamentally dangerous.

Comment: you shouldn't parse html/xml with sed/awk, really bad idea

Comment: I know it's generally a bad idea, but it's a really simple task: I have a variable containing  something like that, every time, and I need to extract the file path. While better solutions could exist using other languages, sed seems to be doing that just fine. Thank you all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For simple cases, you can use sed:

```
sed -r 's/.*href="([^"]+).*/\1/g'
```

Comment: This is GNU sed only as a note

Answer (score 2):

After the required warning *Please Don't Parse HTML with Bash, sed, other simple tools*, in this case:

```
$ echo "$var"
<a onclick="return:false;" href="https://example.com/file-X.Y.Z.zip"><div class="btn">Linux</div></a>
$ echo "$var" | sed -E 's/^.*href/href/; s/>.*//'
href="https://example.com/file-X.Y.Z.zip"
```

Or, pure Bash:

```
$ [[ $var =~ (href=\"[^\"]*\") ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
href="https://example.com/file-X.Y.Z.zip"
```

Comment: Exactly. This may or may not work depending on how crusty your HTML is. This will easily be confused by *any* instance of `href=` in your code, regardless of where it appears.

Answer (score 1):

Bash should not be used for that kind of thing, but you can use `grep`:

```
html='<a onclick="return:false;" href="https://example.com/file-X.Y.Z.zip"><div class="btn">Linux</div></a>'

echo "$html" | grep -o 'href="[^"]*' | tail -c +7
```

Using `tail` as well to strip off `href=` part will print:

```
https://example.com/file-X.Y.Z.zip
```

---

And if you want just the filename, you could do:

```
filename=$(basename $(echo "$html" | grep -o 'href="[^"]*' | tail -c +7))
echo "$filename"
```

To get:

```
file-X.Y.Z.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper way is to use XML/HTML parsers for such cases.

[***xmlstarlet***](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html) approach:

```
html_str='<a onclick="return:false;" href="https://example.com/file-X.Y.Z.zip"><div class="btn">Linux</div></a>'

xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//a/@href' -n <<< "$html_str"
https://example.com/file-X.Y.Z.zip
```